# Polynomial Time Solution For a Mixed-Integer Linear Programming Specific Case

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, algorithms, computational-complexity

Consider the following mixed-integer linear programming (MILP):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{maximize}  & 1 & \\
\text{subject to}& x_{i} \geq 0,  &i=1 ,\dots, m\\
                 & y_{i} \geq 0,  &i=1 ,\dots, m\\  
                 & z_{i} \geq 0,  &i=1 ,\dots, m\\  
                 & x_{i}+y_{i}+z_{i} = 1,  &i=1 ,\dots, m\\
                 & \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i}x_{i} =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i}{3}\\
                 & \sum_{i=1}^m b_{i}y_{i} =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m b_i}{3}\\
                 & \sum_{i=1}^m c_{i}z_{i} =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m c_i}{3}\\
                 & \text{$x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i}$ are integers for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$,} \\
                 & \text{except one $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$ for which $x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i}$ are reals} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

It is already proved that if $a_{i} = b_{i} = c_{i}$, then the problem has a polynomial time solution.

Questions:

- Is this specific case of MILP can be resolved in polynomial time?
- If not, how can I prove that this special case is NP-hard?
- In general, are there some generic ways to prove that a specific MILP is NP-hard or has a polynomial-time solution?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by your first question. Are you asking whether this problem can be solved in polynomial time? Are you referring to the case where $a_i = b_i = c_i$?

Comment: If $a_i = b_i = c_i$, a polynomial time solution exists. My question is referring to the general case, where $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ can be equals or not.

Comment: However, if you have a polynomial solution for the case where $a_i = b_i = c_i$, I would enjoy to read it.